# Does readlines() close the file?

Tags: python

Is there a need to close a file after doing:

```
lines = open(fname).readlines()
```

Or does `readlines()` close the file after reading the data? If not, how should it be closed?

Comment: `with open(fname) as file: ..` - https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm (eg.)

Comment: FWIW, the question might be slightly more interesting if it was: "Does `open(file).readlines()` automatically close the file?"; it's also a slightly different question, as readlines is merely using the open file in such a case, and not presented as being explicitly in control (which it is not).

Comment: The reason why this distinction matters: `global_f = open(file); global_f.readlines()` - the file will not be closed until the program ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does fp.readlines() close a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508271/does-fp-readlines-close-a-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough to check empirically whether `readlines` closes the file:

```
>>> f = open("so.py")
>>> lines = f.readlines()
>>> f.closed
False
>>> f.close()
>>> f.closed
True
```

A little thought suggests that `readlines` should *not* close the file: even with the file "bookmark" at EOF, there are useful commands, starting with `seek`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the method itself does not close the file automatically. At some point (reliably?) it will be closed if there are no more references to it anywhere in your code, but that is not done by the `readlines` method. You can either do the closing explicitly:

```
f = open(...)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

Or:

```
lines = []
with open(...) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Or depend on the garbage collector to do it for you, by not maintaining any reference to the file object:

```
lines = open(...).readlines()
```

Which is what you have already, and which will probably be fine in most circumstances. I don't know the level of guarantee that the garbage collector gives you there.

Comment: Won't the 'GC' ensure `file.close` "at some point in the very near future" in this case? There is no cylic ref established AFAIK and CPython has a relatively deterministic implementation.. whether "correct" or not, it's a different pattern than holding onto the opened file in a variable (eg.)

Comment: Isn't `lines` a list of strings? It won't have a `close` method.

Comment: In the presented example in the question, the file object is not saved in any visible/leaked intermediary name..

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, but the question is whether the `readlines` method does the actual closing. Which it doesn't, so I was trying to keep my explanation more general in case OP had other use cases in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `with` statement if you really wanted to, which would close the file without you having to call `f.close()`. (See [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) for guidance on using `with` in Python.) But @mypetition's answer is certainly the least painful option.

Comment: Yikes! I fell into the same trap as @mypetition... Editing my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't close the file, but you don't have to worry about it, Your file will be closed automatically before it's Garbage collected.

CPython use reference count to clear objects and clearly there is no variable pointing to the object returned by `open`, so it will be Garbage collected, and python close them before that.

Comment: The `readlines` method does not close the file, the garbage collector does.